# Avoiding Dovescape's Effect

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I’ve noticed [Dovescape](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDovescape%5d) uses the specific word “cast” to trigger its ability, and I am curious about what effects circumvent its wording.

Will the following effects skirt through Dovescape?

- [Dualcaster Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDualcaster%20Mage%5d) copying a not yet countered spell on the stack
- [Ral, Storm Conduit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRal%2c%20Storm%20Conduit%5d) ’s [-2] ability which would copy the next spell you attempt to cast, the Copy being unaffected since it was not “cast”
- Also related [Spark Double](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpark%20Double%5d) (or [Clever Impersonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClever%20Impersonator%5d)) cloning an already in play Planewalker (Or any nonland/noncreature)
- Feel free to include additional effects which would improve this question.

Comment: How would spark double/clever impersonator copying an in play permanent circumvent dovescape? It would still be countered upon cast.... is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: @CollinB I'm looking for clarification, the cards in question are creature spells in hand, and non-creatures on the battlefield. Both use wording along the lines of "May enter as." So how does that work in conjunction with Dovescape?

Comment: @CollinB see the answer I posted.  Dovescape is checking for non-creature spells and SD/CI are creature spells on the stack.

Comment: @DenisS right, duh, forgot dovescape was noncreature. I was asking under the assumption that it countered creatures as well

Comment: Also of note is that Dovescape doesn't check to see if the spell was actually countered.  So Counterflux could counter a creature, and you would still get three doves.

Comment: @L.P. added a section for a few different ways to circumvent Dovescape.  It's a difficult card to get around without creature-based enchantment removal but it can be done.

Comment: There are cards like Absolver Thrull that can get rid of it. Arbiter of the Ideal lets you put artifacts on the battlefield. If you can splice a spell onto a creature spell, you'll get its effects. Boseiju, Who Shelters All makes your instants and sorceries uncounterable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The copy of the spell from the ETB effect of [Dualcaster Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDualcaster%20Mage%5d) will not be countered by [Dovescape](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDovescape%5d).  You are correct in saying that copies of spells are not cast, and thus do not trigger [Dovescape](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDovescape%5d).  This is also correct in the case of using [Ral, Storm Conduit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRal%2c%20Storm%20Conduit%5d)'s -2 ability.

[Spark Double](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpark%20Double%5d) and [Clever Impersonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClever%20Impersonator%5d) will work as well.  These cards are creature spells on the stack and would not trigger [Dovescape](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDovescape%5d).

From the rulings on Clever Impersonator

> You choose which nonland permanent Clever Impersonator will copy, if any, as it enters the battlefield. This doesn’t target that nonland permanent.

Once it enters the battlefield copying a Planeswalker, it's already been cast and resolved.  It's too late to counter it.

To see, step by step, how it would work, here's how the interaction would play out.

1. Player A casts Clever Impersonator.
2. Dovescape does not see a non-creature spell cast, and thus doesn't trigger.
3. Both players pass, and Clever Impersonator resolves.
4. At this time, Player A choses the Planeswalker to have Clever Impersonator copy, and it enters the battlefield as a Planeswalker.  Dovescape doesn't trigger because a spell wasn't cast.

---

With regards to other ways to get around Dovescape, there aren't a whole lot of options.

- There are ways to make noncreature spells be uncounterable.

  - [These cards](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20[%22This%20spell%20can%27t%20be%20countered.%22]&type=%20![%22Creature%22]) would get around Dovescape, as they all say "This spell can't be countered."
  - [Veil of Summer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVeil%20of%20Summer%5d) and [Determined](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDetermined%5d) can prevent spells from being countered for the rest of the turn if you can get them through Dovescape (see below).  Similarly [Overmaster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOvermaster%5d) prevents the next spell from being countered, if you can get it through Dovescape.
  - [Taigam, Ojutai Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTaigam%2c%20Ojutai%20Master%5d) is a creature that prevents instants and sorceries from being countered (and dragons, but that doesn't matter for Dovescape)
  - [Thryx, the Sudden Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThryx%2c%20the%20Sudden%20Storm%5d) is a creature that prevents spells with converted mana cost 5 or more from being countered
  - [Boseiju, Who Shelters All](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBoseiju%2c%20Who%20Shelters%20All%5d) is a land that makes instants and sorceries uncounterable with it's mana ability
  - [Destiny Spinner](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDestiny%20Spinner%5d) is a creature that makes Enchantment spells uncounterable
- Dovescape's ability is a triggered ability.  [There are cards that exist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20[%22Counter%20target%22]%20[%22triggered%20abilit%22]) that allow you to counter triggered abilities, but with the exception of one in particular, are all non-creature spells that would also get countered by Dovescape. [Nimble Obstructionist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNimble%20Obstructionist%5d) is the one exception, as cycling a card is not casting a spell, and it's triggered ability from cycling can counter Dovescape's effect
- The keyword ability Storm creates copies of itself for each time a spell had been previously cast.  The Dovescape ability will counter the original spell, but not any of the copies.

Answer (score 7):

Copies of spells are not cast, so they will not trigger Dovescape.

> 706.10. To copy a spell, activated ability, or triggered ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; **a copy of a spell isn’t cast** and a copy of an activated ability isn’t activated.

The copy does still count as a spell, but it is not ever cast. This applies to all of your examples; none of them would cause Dovescape to trigger.

Comment: Beat me by 11 seconds!

Comment: I appreciate the specific ruling for copies with emphasis